# How can I add in-store credit to my Ruby On Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add store credit to my app like what fiverr or other online marketplaces have where users can have some credit or money in their accounts. Is there any gem or some recommended steps to help me build this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Credit** is a little intense because you have to balance it with actual money. When you get into that world, you need to make sure the app works properly.

Nonetheless, you'd have to set up an extra model and some other things to get it working.

The two aspects you require are *storage* (a model) and *payment* (mechanics to accept money). These will permit your app to accept payments, and then have a way to store them (giving you a balance to work with).

The setup would not be overly complicated; you'll have a *payments* model which will literally just store all the money a user has sent - you'll be able to get the balance through your `User` model:

---

**Storage**

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | username | email | etc etc etc
   has_many :payments

   def balance
      payments.sum(:value) #-> @user.balance -> "25"
   end
end

#app/models/payment.rb
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | user_id | value | currency | transaction_id | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This will give you the ability to have the following setup:

```
#users
id username   email
1  joe_bloggs joe_bloggs@yahoo.com

#payments
id user_id value currency transaction_id
1  1       17.00 USD      XB56YTSG3F5F
2  1        7.00 USD      YU8953FG5RED
3  1       -5.00 USD      NIL
```

One of the important things to note here is the `transaction_id` in your *Payment* model. This is important because it allows you to leave the *transaction* data (IE payment information) with the provider you use (more below).

A typical issue with many developers is to try and store all their own data. Whilst this gives them great data sets, it also means you have to maintain it all. Storing a *`transaction_id`* for your payments.

You'll also note the negative value in `payments#3`. This is to demonstrate user-to-user payment (IE the *spending* of in-store credit). This has to be worked on, but that can come later.

--

**Payment**

The second piece of the puzzle is to use a payment processor.

The favourite is [*stripe*](https://stripe.com/gb) but there are others, like Paypal etc.

In terms of stripe, it's quite involved to get it set up. However, if you play your cards right, you'll be able to do it using the following setup:

```
#config/routes.rb
resource :profile do
   resources :payments #-> url.com/profile/payments/new
end

#app/controllers/payments_controller.rb
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user! #-> if using Devise, which is highly recommended

    def index
        @payments = current_user.payments
    end

    def new
       @payment = Payment.new #-> has to work with stripe, that's another question
    end

    def create
       @payment = Payment.new payment_params #-> this should take the stripe return data & save it in your model
       @payment.save
    end

    private

    def payment_params
       params.require....
    end
end
```

An important note.

Stripe only provides the *functionality* to receive payment. Your `Payment` model should store your transactions in *your* dataset.

As mentioned, the smart thing to do will be to keep their transaction data on file within your payment processor, referring to the `transaction_id` as you need. However, you have to store the payment data in your own database to get it working properly.

---

There are a number of pre-packed solutions for this type of functionality:

- [Shoppe](http://tryshoppe.com/)
- [Piggybak](http://www.piggybak.org/)
- [Spree (SAAS)](https://spreecommerce.com/)
- [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=23)